# Translating "invited lecturer at the Winter School..."

Tags: traduction, anglais, éducation, université, supérieur

How can I translate for a French CV the following:

> invited lecturer at the Winter School...

and

> invited lecture at the Winter School...

I have seen many variations (linguee even gives examples with Winter School as it is) but I cannot pick up the proper ones.
Even my French colleagues do not share the same opinions.
I am wondering also why the word “lecturer” exists in Canadian French and not in the French of the hexagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lecteur* exists but is restricted to language teaching.

The term "lecturer" has different meanings depending on the country. If this position includes both research and teaching, the translation would be ***maître de conférences invité***. It can be found in [official documents](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexteArticle.do;jsessionid=ED0837046CF3003AC22AA5D99076D437.tplgfr25s_2?idArticle=JORFARTI000036609010&cidTexte=JORFTEXT000036608981&dateTexte=29990101&categorieLien=id). If research is not part of the job, that might be ***attaché, adjoint*** or ***assistant d'enseignement invité***, ***intervenant extérieur***<sup>1</sup> or just ***conférencier***.

Regarding *winter school*, the expression seems to be sometimes used untranslated but we also use ***école or université d'hiver***, just like *summer school* commonly translates to ***[école or université d'été](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_d%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9)***.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thanks to Flying_whale for suggesting it!</sub>

Comment: Maître de conférences invité ? C'est bizarre quand même car Maître de conférences c'est l'équivalent de associate/assistant professor. Il me paraît plus logique que français canadien emploie lecturer tel il est (au moins livio dit comme ça).

Comment: @dimitris on pourrait aussi utiliser `intervenant extérieur`, pour remplacer `invited lecturer` si j'ai bien saisi le contexte

Comment: Cela varie peut être selon les domaines mais j'entends bien plus souvent **école d'été/d'hiver** que **université d'été/d'hiver**.

Comment: @Delta-u Très juste, je l'ajoute. merci !